# @font-face c# MVC Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, css-font-face

Tenho um template Bootstrap que estou tentando aplicar em um projeto, porém tenho uma enorme dificuldade em importar os arquivos .eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff, .otf

Esses arquivos estão no diretório: `NomeProjeto\Content\fonts`

Meu arquivo .css que chamo tenta utilizar esses arquivos está no diretório: `NomeProjeto\Content\fonts`.

Estou tentando referenciar da seguinte maneira:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?              v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'); font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, alguma idéia?

Obrigado.

Comment: Se o seu arquivo css está no mesmo diretório que o diretório de fonts, você não precisa adicionar os "../" antes do caminho. Ao meu ver é isso. Não entendi muito bem a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Para adicionar as configurações adicionais que você quer você precisa acessar a pasta App_start e no arquivo: "BundleConfig.cs".  adicionar os arquivos CSS ou JS que você deseja.

Answer (score 0):

Como a resolução de referências é feita por rota, e não por diretório estático, é preciso configurar a aplicação para permitir rotas estáticas por tipo de arquivo. Isto se faz colocando no seguinte no `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/truetype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
<configuration>
```

Outra coisa é que você não precisa referenciar os arquivos da descrição do `@font-face` por diretório relativo. Pode fazer assim:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
    src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?              v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'); font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```